# Julia: Equivalent of *args from Python in Julia?

Tags: julia

Is there an equivalent command to *args from Python in Julia?  I ask because I am trying to write a numerical integration function, the argument of which is a function that may depend on several constants.  For example, if my Julia function was

```
function func(x,a,b)
return a*x + b
end
```

is there way that I could make an array

`args = [a,b]`

and call this function as

`val = func(x,*args)`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please finish the tour and you will understand [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. With your stated trail and error code... people are more willing to help you so both can learn. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: Knock yourself out [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/) to learn the language. Then show some effort you tried... at least something that looks like "I tried to solve my own question".

Answer (score 6):

This is quite easy in Julia. Putting `...` after the last argument in a function definition makes it accept any number of arguments passed as a tuple:

```
function func(x,args...)
    result = zero(x*args[1])
    for (i,arg) in enumerate(args)
        result += arg * x^(length(args) - i) 
    end
    result
end
```

and you can call it either way:

```
args = [a, b]
val = func(x, args...)

# or
val = func(x, a, b)
```

Comment: What you're showing is something different (namely how you can pass an _arbitrary_ number of arguments to a function, also known as a "variadic" function). What OP wants is simpler. Given an already defined `func(x,a,b)` function, they just need to call it as `func(x, args...)`